# UI responsiveness lags after loading a page

Tags: windows, user-interface, wildfly

I'm developing a web app running on WildFly 8.2 and I'm experiencing annoying UI responsiveness lags that I do know how to pinpoint. The lags occur shortly after loading a new page - they last about 3-4 seconds during which all UI is not responsive (such as hovering does not have effect, you cannot close the window or open DevTools)

I considered the following aspects:

- **code-related** - angular, animations, kendo, less.js, not optimized selectors or iterators in my code, etc. Disproved - I rolled back to a very early version where I had never observed the problem (so to eliminate a hidden impact of newly introduced features), and the problem was there too.
- **CPU-related** - restarted afresh many a time, running no extra apps - no go.
- **server-related**
- **browser-related** - disabled extensions and hardware acceleration setting - disproved. Chrome/FF usually silently choke, sometimes asking whether to close unresponsive page, IE complains about script, but when I choose to *Debug the script*, all I get is being directed to random script.

The key test however was to view my local deployment over LAN from other desktops - the app performed sluggishly regardless, whereas the same app (same code, same branch revision) deployed locally on those desktops performed superbly.

So this proved this is more server- or CPU related stuff. The app ran fine on WildFly 8.0. When the problem started to bite, I upgraded to 8.2 but it does not seem to have any effect.

As I'm running out of ideas, does anyone seem to have a hint what to do/check next?

Last minute: I went along the advice from here http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/1843-73-windows-slow-browsing-chrome-firefox-faster and turned off Windows Defender's real-time protection - nothing got better.

Comment: If it's slow over the LAN, but speedy when running locally it sounds like a network issue. I'd look at the number of round trips you're making to the server.

Comment: What kind of app is this exactly? Can you share some info about the UI technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by invisible content (shown on request in a modal) that grew up to 5000+ table rows and was employing angular binding (`ng-repeat` a.o.). Thanks for your hints.